# Ristretto Image Viewer in XUbuntu does not open .CR2 images. Bug? or not supported?

Tags: xubuntu, image-viewers, ristretto

**Context:**

Image Viewer (the default viewer in Xubuntu) does not show images with extension `.cr2` (the raw image of Canon version 2). If I try, the program opens but no images are displayed. And NO errors are prompt.

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to enable the feature? Maybe some extension of the Image Viewer?
- If not, are there other alternatives?

Comment: My favorite Search Engine claims that Shotwell and Gimp can open cr2 files. File a bug against Ristretto for the invalid open (`ubuntu-bug ristretto`)

Comment: It's not a bug (I don't think), it's just not supported. There are alternatives that will open `.cr2` files. One such application is XNView - which is free as in beer but not opensource - and there's an XNViewMP with a .deb for easy installation.

Comment: @KGIII it's not a bug if it returns a useful error "*Sorry, I don't know how to read that*" or other intended behavior. Opening a blank window (or no window) and leaving the user confused does not seem like normally intended behavior. Hence bug for that specific behavior, regardless of whether the format is supported or not.

Comment: @karel, they should.  I can try on Monday the solution

Comment: Please try 2 different apps if possible so that you can compare the color accuracy of both apps side by side.